# How to search from multiple values in single field (Bus Stops in GTFS)?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gtfs

In the GTFS data for Denver, the BUS_STOPS table stores multiple comma-separated values in the ROUTES column:

```
28, 19, 44, 10, 32
```

I'm selecting BUS_ROUTES that are within a distance of a school.

But to select the corresponding stops along those routes means trying to find a bus stop (ex. that serves bus 44) from the list I described above - I'm not sure how to do this.

The comment below helped me figure out selecting 1 route by its value would look like this:

```
select * from BUS_STOPS where ROUTES like '% 44,%';
```

...which returns records that contain 44 in one of the listed values.

So how would I replace the static value of 44 to be the value of the ROUTES field in the BUS_ROUTES table?

The BUS_ROUTES table looks like this:

[image]

...and the BUS_STOPS table looks like this:

[image]

I'm using PostgreSQL to query the GTFS data.

Comment: select...from BUS_STOPS  where ROUTES like '% 44,%';

Comment: Oh! How can that work if I want to match it against the ROUTE field of the bus routes? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: ok. here you are supposed to populate what you have done so far. Please update the question with result of this qry: `select * from BUS_STOPS where ROUTES like '% 44,%';`

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks, I think I've made the appropriate update.

Comment: I C now. you want to join two tables?.. show the sample of `BUS_ROUTES` TABLE

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks - trying to figure out how to get text from pgadmin rather than screen shots...

Comment: @VaoTsun thanks for your help - an answer was posted below... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to an array, then use an array comparison:

```
select * 
from BUS_STOPS 
where '44' = any(string_to_array(routes,',')
```

This can also be used as a join condition:

```
select * 
from BUS_STOPS s
   join bus_routes r on string_to_array(s.routes,',') @> string_to_array(r.routes,',')
```

The `@>` is the "contains" operator and tests if the left array (bus_stops.routes) contains all elements from right array (`bus_routes.routes`). Another option would be to the use overlaps operator `&&` - it's not clear to me what exactly you want